# Magento Template - AJAX Issues

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento

[Site](http://www.JRCTest.com):

Build:    `Magento v1.0.9.1`

ISSUES:   I have a few issues that seem to be related to AJAX within my theme.

The first is with the Onepage Checkout. In Firefox and IE, I enter the address I want to ship to and then click "Continue" only to see the "Loading next step" continuously "load". However in Chrome it works fine.

The next issue is with the Ajaxcart Super module. When I enable it and try to add a product to the cart from the front page, the page just constantly loads. Another probable AJAX issue.

Lastly, I am using the extension from the following link for Layered Navigation. In my template, whenever I select one filter, it works. However if I then select another filter from a different group, it will eliminate the first filter. If the attributes are in the same set, it filters them okay- just if you change groups. To make it weirder, if I manually append the filters in the URL , it will actually use both filters. Just when it's clicked.

```
http://www.manadev.com/magento-extensions/seo-layered-navigation-plus
```

The following link will show you multiple filters being successfully used:

```
http://www.jrctest.com/computers/notebooks.html?e_processor_core=10154&e_touchscreen=5750&e_brand_name=1692
```

Note that the URL contains the filters. If you click to remove one or if you select a different filter, ALL of the currently used filters will be dropped.

Any thoughts on this? I would certainly appreciate any help I could get.

Comment: Each question should contain only one issue, you need to split your question into 3 self-cintaining questions.

Comment: I believe all three issues are likely the result of the same cause. Therefore I thought it would be helpful to provide as many symptoms of the cause as possible. My apologies.